# Where is the graphical editor for the Android Manifest file located in Android Studio 1.5.1?

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

I am currently following a textbook and after creating an app, it shows how to edit the Android manifest file using the graphical editor. It shows in my textbook that after opening the XML file, you will see tabs at the bottom, and clicking application will give you the graphical editor. However, open the XML file, I do not have these tabs, and am only show the XML file's code. While it is definitely easy enough to do everything they are showing by editing the XML file directly, I would still like to be able to view the graphical editor so I may also be familiar with that. Does anyone know where this is located at? The textbook is from 2015 so I am assuming they are using an older version of Android studio.

Comment: There is no "graphical editor" for the manifest in Android Studio that I am aware of. Eclipse used to have tabs with structured editors for most of the manifest, but that never made it over to Android Studio. There is a graphical editor for layout resources, and a few other specialized editors (e.g., translation grid for strings).

Comment: Bro use xml directly, no need for GUI

Comment: @CommonsWare This is what I am referring to http://i.imgur.com/PcaTk84.png?1

Comment: @meda I easily could, I would just like to see how to be able to do this as well. See my above comment for what I am referring to, I believe I used the wrong terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot is from Eclipse, not Android Studio.

Comment: Hmm that's strange, as the book says they are using Android Studio. I guess this must have slipped when they updated the book for the second edition. So nothing like this exists in Android Studio?

Comment: @JoshNicholson: Correct. Frankly, the Eclipse one was really awkward. I never used it, other than the Permissions sub-tab. It's not out of the question that they'll add something like this someday, but it's not there through Android Studio 1.5.1.

Comment: @JoshNicholson - nope! you need to update that book i guess.